# How to update Data source in Rdlc Active report,after adding new fields in dataset from view

Tags: sql, rdlc, activereports

```
Select * FROM Customerdatasource
```

Comment: thank you for using ActiveReports.
Your question is not clear, do you want to update the data source in designer or at runtime?   do you mean you updated your database and added some new fields and you want those to show up in the dataset view?   you can simply refresh the dataset.

Comment: Yes, I want to update data source in Designer.

Comment: I have added some new fields and there is no option for refresh dataset,there is only "Edit " and "Remove" Data set . I'm using active report v15

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue. Save your design and re-open it. If that does not work then you will need to remove the dataset and add it again. Doublecheck that your dataset is truly using the view you modified.

Comment: Yes ,Or simply add a space after your query it will enable the Tick button and you can refresh your dataset from Query.'m Using this  approach.